# Customize Bearer keyword with nuxt

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, bearer-token

I'm trying to connect a Nuxt PWA with Django REST framework with Bearer auth.
I need to change the keyword "Bearer" for "token" on Nuxt.

Nuxt Auth v4 gives me:

```
Authorization: Bearer ba0bd40f588e...
```

I need

```
Authorization: token ba0bd40f588e...
```

My nuxt config:

```
auth: {
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: 'api-token-auth/', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
      user: { url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
      logout: false,
    },
  },
},
resetOnError: true,
scopeKey: 'groups',
},
```

I already tried:

```
token: {
      property: 'token',
      type: 'token',
      name: 'token'
    },
```

I remember this was possible, please help

Comment: Nuxt has a documentation page explaining this at https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local/ but reading the above, I assume you tried this and it didn't work?

You have also tried the obvious deleting your browser cache, hard reloading the page, etc?

Can you supply some information about your development environment?
Browser and version:
NuxtJS version:

Comment: thanks @SplinterReality it was probably the cache and my exhaustion, it's working now with `type: 'token'` curiously chrome still shows  `Authorization: Bearer ba0...`